# Asserting properties in a custom NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm not too sure if I should of made another question for this or expanded on the last question, please correct me if I wasn't meant to.

I've currently got this code working:

```
if ([ myArray containsObject:@"Object1" ] && [ myArray containsObject:@"Object 2"]) {
return YES;
} 

else {
return NO;
}
```

What I'm needing to do is modify this so it iterates through an array and accesses an Objects property value. For example:

```
if (myArray contains obj.ID 1 & 2) {
    return YES
}
else{
    return NO;
}
```

Any suggestions on what I should look at? I've been at this for a couple of hours and tried different permutations with no luck.

Thank you!

Comment: unrelated, use `return [some methodcall]` instead of `if [some methodcall] return YES else return NO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -indexOfObjectPassingTest: to check if an object with a particular attribute value is in your array. The method returns either the object's index if it is found or NSNotFound if not.

Thus, assuming your objects are e.g. NSDictionaries and they have NSNumbers as IDs, you could do something like this:

```
if([myArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [[obj objectForKey:@"ID"] intValue]==1;
}]!=NSNotFound && [myArray indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [[obj objectForKey:@"ID"] intValue]==2;
}]!=NSNotFound)
{
    //Array contains objects
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the first object, you can use `-indexOfObjectPassingTest:` as mpramat says. If you want all the objects in the array that match your criteria, use `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:`.

It takes a block as a parameter. The block evaluates each object and returns YES or know to let the method know if that object should be part of the set of objects that pass the test.